# Elasticsearch cardinality multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index which is as follows:

```
 {
        "_index" : "r2332",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Vl81o3oBs8vUbHSMCZVQ",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "maid" : "d8ee3c5e-babb-4777-9cba-17fb0cd8e8a9",
          "date" : "2021-06-09",
          "hour" : 5,
          "site_id" : 1035
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "r2332",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Xl81o3oBs8vUbHSMCZVQ",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "maid" : "d8ee3c5e-babb-4777-9cba-17fb0cd8e8a9",
          "date" : "2021-06-09",
          "hour" : 5,
          "site_id" : 1897
        }
      }
```

I am trying to get the unique count across maid, date.  I am able to aggregate with one field `maid` but not both.  The following are the codes that I tried.

```
Trial 1:

{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
                "terms": {
                    "site_id": [7560, 7566]
                }
            }, {
                "range": {
                    "date": {
                        "gte": "2021-09-01",
                        "lte": "2021-09-15"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "runtime_mappings": {
        "type_and_promoted": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "script": "emit(doc['maid'].value + ' ' + doc['date'].value)"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "group_by": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "site_id",
                "size": 100
            },
            "aggs": {
                "bydate": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "date",
                        "size": 100
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "byhour": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "hour",
                                "size": 24
                            },
                            "aggs": {
                                "reverse_nested": {},
                                "uv": {
                                    "cardinality": {
                                        "field": "runtime_mappings"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is giving an empty output.

```
Trial 2:

{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
                "terms": {
                    "site_id": [7560, 7566]
                }
            }, {
                "range": {
                    "date": {
                        "gte": "2021-09-01",
                        "lte": "2021-09-15"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "group_by": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "site_id",
                "size": 100
            },
            "aggs": {
                "bydate": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "date",
                        "size": 100
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "byhour": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "hour",
                                "size": 24
                            },
                            "aggs": {
                                "uv": {
                                    "cardinality": {
                                        "script": "doc['maid'].value + '#' +doc'date'].value"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me syntax error at `doc['maid'].value`.  How do I effectively combine two fields for cardinality. I am using Elasticsearch 7.13.2.

The mapping of my index is as follows:

```
  "r2332" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "dynamic" : "false",
      "properties" : {
        "date" : {
          "type" : "date"
        },
        "hour" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "maid" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "reach" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "site_id" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your second query as shown below. You need to use the `maid.keyword` instead of the `maid` field in the cardinality aggregation to avoid the `search_phase_execution_exception`

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "site_id": [
              7560,
              7566
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "2021-09-01",
              "lte": "2021-09-15"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "site_id",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "bydate": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "date",
            "size": 100
          },
          "aggs": {
            "byhour": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "hour",
                "size": 24
              },
              "aggs": {
                "uv": {
                  "cardinality": {
                    "script": "doc['maid.keyword'].value + '#' +doc['date'].value"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support.  I am still getting a syntax error at maid.keyword.

Comment: @Apricot can you please share your index mapping ?

Comment: I have added the mapping to my query.  Thank you.